# How to remove this empty whitespace on sliverappbar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, flutter-sliverappbar

[image]

is there any solution on how to remove this space? i search for any solution but i haven't found it yet, please help me if you know it

this is the code:

```
        SliverAppBar(
              shape: const ContinuousRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(20))),
              pinned: pinned,
              snap: snap,
              floating: floating,
              expandedHeight: 40.0,
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2d3b96),
              flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text(
                  "Presensi Pegawai",
                  maxLines: 1,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 22.0,
                    fontFamily: "IBM-Plex-Sans",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `titlePadding` in `FlexibleSpaceBar`.

```
...
          flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
            titlePadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
              start: 8.0,
              bottom: 16.0,
            ),
            title: Text(
              "Presensi Pegawai",
...
```